# How to create an event with integer and float type in Yahoo! S4

Tags: stream-processing

Suppose that I want to create an event from a Java bean in Yahoo! S4.  I can use the following code to do that:

```
import io.s4.client.Driver
import io.s4.client.Message
Driver d = new Driver(hostName, port);
Message m = new Message(streamName, clazz, string);
d.send(m);
```

Message Constructor Arguments:

- streamName - any name for the stream
- clazz - the fully qualified name of the event class for the stream
- string - the string representation of the object

**Question:**

What would the string representation of the following object look like so that it can be used in an event?

```
public class CarType {

private String carNO;
private String tyreNO;
private double pressureReading;
private long Timer;
private boolean carMoving;

}
```